# GNOME Terminal extended ascii support

Tags: gnome-terminal, locale

I've got this file:

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f 
   __________________________________
20 |  ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / |
30 |0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? |
40 |@ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O |
50 |P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ |
60 |` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o |
70 |p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~  |
80 |                |
90 |                |
a0 |  ¡ ¢ £ € ¥ Š § š © ª « ¬ ­ ® ¯ |
b0 |° ± ² ³ Ž µ ¶ · ž ¹ º » Œ œ Ÿ ¿ |
c0 |À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï |
d0 |Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß |
e0 |à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï |
f0 |ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ÷ ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ |
   __________________________________
```

Its just an ASCII table. How do I make gnome terminal display it properly?  By-default it doesn't display any of the row's symbols except for 1st 6, see screenie:

[image]

My locale is en_US.UTF-8:

```
$locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

fonts are default. Tried changing them, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not "ASCII", but appears to be ISO-8859-1 (also referred to as Latin-1).  You can either

- set your locale to something with that encoding, e.g., `en_US` (depending on what your locale support is), or
- convert the file into UTF-8

You can use `iconv` to do this conversion, e.g., one of these:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 oldfile > newfile
iconv -t UTF-8 oldfile > newfile
```

Further reading:

- [iconv - convert text from one character encoding to another](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html)